# Use rep() and seq() to create a vector

Tags: r

I am new to `R`. In `JAVA` I would introduce a control variable to create a sequence such as

```
1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

I was thinking on doing something like

```
seq(from=c(1:5),to=c(5,10),by=1)
```

However that does not work...

Can that be solved purely with `seq` and `rep`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
rep(0:4, each=5)+seq(from=1, to=5, by=1)


[1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Nice; more concisely: `rep(0:4, each = 5) + 1:5`

Answer (score 4):

Using `outer` is pretty concise:

```r
c(outer(1:5, 0:4, `+`))
#>  [1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

Note, `0:4` is short for `seq(from = 0, to = 4, by = 1)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this. You can create a function to create the sequence and apply to an initial vector `v1`. Here the code:

```
#Data
v1 <- 1:5
#Code
v2 <- c(sapply(v1, function(x) seq(from=x,by=1,length.out = 5)))
```

Output:

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

And the way using `seq()` and `rep()` can be:

```
#Code2
rep(1:5, each = 5) + 0:4
```

Output:

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: A convenient wrapper (now a "primitive") for `sapply(.., seq)` is `sequence`: `sequence(rep(5, 5), 1:5)`

Answer (score 0):

A perfect use case for `Map` or `mapply`. I always prefer Map because it does not simplify the output by default.

```
Map(seq, from = 1:5, to = 5:9)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1] 2 3 4 5 6

[[3]]
[1] 3 4 5 6 7

[[4]]
[1] 4 5 6 7 8

[[5]]
[1] 5 6 7 8 9
```

You can use `unlist()` to get it the way you want.

```
unlist(Map(seq, from = 1:5, to = 5:9))
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
Note that `by = 1`, the default.
```